# Iterate through a list of lists with indexes

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of lists in Python which looks like this:

```
onlyText3 = [['Here', 'is', 'some', 'text'], ['Here', 'is', 'some', 'more', 'text']]
```

I need to iterate through every element of that list to

1. Check whether the word is contained in a dictionary
2. If the word is not in the dictionary and if it is a compound word split it up + add the resulting words to the list
3. Replace unknown words with the first suggestion the dictionary provides (splitter.split('word') returns a list)

Im working with Pyenchant and the word-compound-splitter.

This is my code:

```
import enchant
import splitter

dictionary = enchant.dict("en_US")

for a in range(len(onlyText3)-1):
     for b in range(len(onlyText3[a])-1):
         if dictionary.check(onlyText3[a][b]):
             pass
         elif splitter.split(onlyText3[a][b]):
             for c in range(len(splitter.split(onlyText3[a][b]))-1):
                 onlyText3[a].insert(b+c, splitter.split(onlyText3[a][b])[c])
         else:
             if dictionary.suggest(onlyText3[a][b]): 
                 onlyText3[a][b] = dictionary.suggest(onlyText3[a][b])[0]
```

However, this yields an Index-Error:

```
onlyText3[a].insert(b+c, splitter1.split(onlyText3[a][b])[c])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there something I have not thought through? Is there maybe an easier way to do this?
I could not think of any better way since I do need to access each element with its index because I need the index in order to insert the words resulting from splitting up the compound words.

Answer (score 0):

`insert` doesn't extend the list for you automatically. Try doing `onlyText3[a].extend([None] * (b + c - len(onlyText3[a])))` before the line that breaks.